# How exclude paths from Mocha using regexp

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm using mocha to run unit test in a project with multiple modules, sometimes including node_modules.

```
src
|_module1
  |_dir
  |_test
    |_unit
|_module2
  |_dir
  |_test
    |_unit
|_module3
  |_dir
  |_test
    |_unit
  |_node_modules
    |_test
    |_unit
|_module4
  |_dir1
  |_test
    |_unit
  |_node_modules
    |_test
    |_unit
  |_dir2
  |_test
    |_unit
  |_node_modules
    |_test
    |_unit
```

I would like exclude all node_modules directories and somes directories in different sub dir.

I have tested lot of pattern like `src/!(module4|node_modules)/**/test/unit/**/*.js` but it seems doesn't work like the `--exclude` parameter

It still scan unit tests in the node_modules dir from subdir in module4

Also I would like avoid to use `find` command cause it shoud work on any platform.

Could you help please ?